# How to split using the regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, php-7

In order to split the given notation ,I initially used

```
list($pdf_platform_size, $pdf_capacity ,$pdf_accuracy) = split("[a-z-][a-z-]", $pdf_select_specification);
```

When the given string was say **6 x 3m - 20t - 2kg** it used to seperate the given into 6x3m for **$pdf_platform_size** , 20t for **$pdf_capacity**, and 2kg for **$pdf_accuracy**.

But now as i upgraded to PHP 7, and split is deprecated.Using the same for **preg_split()** doesn't seem to work.
I tried `list($a,$b,$c) = preg_split("/[a-z-][a-z-]/", $x);`

where $x is **6 x 3m - 20t - 2kg**

But am not getting the desired result.Looking for some help here

Comment: In your first line of code you're missing the REGEX delimiters `/` and `/` on `preg_split()`.

Comment: But not in second one... @Utkanos

Comment: Yes, but which should we assume you're using?

Comment: I'm not the original poster but for sure the second. @Utkanos

Comment: edit has been done, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Regular Expressions if you are splitting on a `-` alone. Use `explode` instead:

```
[$a, $b, $c] = explode('-', '6x3m-20t-2kg');
echo $a; // 6x3m
```

*Note: Shorthand array destructuring came with PHP 7.1*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($pdf_platform_size, $pdf_capacity ,$pdf_accuracy) = array_map('trim', explode(' - ', $pdf_select_specification));
```

If you want the platform_size without those spaces, use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) after that.

Comment: @Toto thanks, man, Fixed! Just code used into a helper of mine and I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use `explode`, but you could also use `preg_split`

```
$x = '6 x 3m - 20t - 2kg';
list($a,$b,$c) = preg_split("/[-]/", $x);
```

If the space are present you may want to `trim()` the result

Answer (score 0):

If you want values you can extract it using `preg_match_all`

```
$x = '6 x 3m - 20t - 2kg';
preg_match_all('/(\d)+[ ]*x[ ]*(\d)+m[ ]*-[ ]*(\d)+t[ ]*-[ ]*(\d)kg/', $x, $dump);
var_dump($dump);
```